# Flex Air: Missing "Export Release Build" button

Tags: apache-flex, air

So I was working normally, and accidentally hit the profiling button... after that, I later decided to export my current .air

This is what I saw:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw6nd.png

Why would the export button disappear all the sudden? I cannot find it at all. It seems rather interesting... not being able to export a .air and provide an installer.. anyone know where I might be able to get this back?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different perspectives in eclipse change things.  The "Export Release Build" is not in the profiler perspective, but it is in the Debug and Flash perspectives.

Switch back to one of the other perspectives or select "File--> Export-->Release Build"; which is available on all perspectives.